# Evaluating a DelayedExpansion variable as a drive letter when checking for file existence

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, delayedvariableexpansion

I've got this block of code that's supposed to check for USB drives, then if they have a file that tags them as one of my utility drives, it runs a robocopy sync on them to make sure they're current.

The problem is it's not evaluating the path for the file correctly. If I `echo "!curDrive!\file.txt"` It prints `\file.txt"`

The relevant (cleaned up/anonymized) bits of script are:

```
@echo off
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%d in ('wmic logicaldisk where "drivetype=2 and access=0" get name /format:value') DO (
    SET "curDrive=%%d"
    echo Looping variable set to %%d
    echo Current drive set to !curDrive!
    if exist "!curDrive!\file.txt" (
        ...
    )
)
```

The echos I've put in for debugging, and I get the expected output on all iterations, e.g.,

```
Looping variable set to L:
Current drive set to L:
```

Comment: I suspect your command `wmic logicaldisk where "drivetype=2 and access=0" get name /format:value` is not returning what you think it is.

Comment: Oops, just thought to add in an edit that it's got what it should, tested via some temporary echos.

Comment: Add `ECHO %%d` and `ECHO !curDrive!` right after the line `SET "curDrive=%%d"`. Does either show what you expect?

Comment: They both show what's expected, yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
@echo off
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f %%d in ('wmic logicaldisk where "drivetype=2 and access=0" get name^|find ":"') DO (
    SET "curDrive=%%d"
    if exist "!curDrive!\file.txt" (
       Echo found it. 
    ) ELSE (
       Echo File not found. 
    )
)
```

You're returning extra carriage returns that need to be filtered out.

Comment: Brilliant! That's what I get for cobbling together scraps without fully understanding. This did the trick nicely, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another method you can use in a defined system, looking for a unique file on a drive and then running robocopy.  Add the rest of the drive letters.

```
@echo off
for %%a in (c d e f g h i j) do if exist "%%a:\unique-file.txt" echo found the file.
```